# Binary search list of Tuples for nearest value >=

Tags: c#, datetime, binary-search

Given a:

```
List<Tuple<DateTime, int>>
```

Where the list is provided ordered by the `DateTime` value `descending`.

How can I use the `.BinarySearch()` method to find the smallest index of a value where the `DateTime` is `>=` than a specified value?

EG, with values:

```
[0] = 29th Jan
[1] = 25th Jan
[2] = 20th Jan
[3] = 10th Jan
[4] = 3rd Jan
```

The results for searches would be:

```
1st Jan = return 4
5th Jan = return 3
28th Jan = return 0
1st Feb = return something else indicating nothing found (eg -1 or null)
```

Comment: why do you have to use `BinarySearch` ?

Comment: @MongZhu the list is given ordered, and will continue to grow over time.  It's a commonly hit method that is used on every page load so needs to be performant.  Linq query will be fast enough for now, but could become an issue further down the line.

Comment: your question is wrong i guess. `find the smallest index of a value`, smallest index for `1st Jan` would be `0` since array is in descending order. you should say find largest index or last index.

Comment: `BinarySearch` seeks specific values using equality, not a greater-than or less-than comparison.  You could easily implement your own version though.  It's a simple algorithm.

Comment: The last comments are interesting - so you were not trying to find the index of the element whos date is == to some value and then count the values "below" it (a.k.a smaller that that date) and then use that index to count?

Comment: minor aside: you could switch this to `List<(DateTime,int)>` with **very** little change, and it would be much friendlier to the GC. Plus you can give the properties meaningful names like `List<(DateTime CreationDate,int RecordId)>`

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius no, the goal is to find the start and end index of the list where the dates fall between two values

Comment: `List<T>.BinarySearch` returns the index the item would exist at if not found, so it looks like you just need your own `IComparer<Tuple<DateTime, int>>`?

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you!  Will use this going forwards although finding it difficult to return in this format from a compiled linq query.

Comment: @TomGullen you'd have to try it, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your list is ordered in reverse to what `BinarySearch` expects, your comparison method needs to return the inverse of date's comparison result:

```
class TupleCompare : IComparer<Tuple<DateTime,int>> {
    public static readonly TupleCompare Instance = new TupleCompare();
    public int Compare(Tuple<DateTime,int> x, Tuple<DateTime,int> y) {
        return -x.Item1.CompareTo(y.Item1); // Note the negative here
    }
}
```

With this comparator in place, call `BinarySearch`, check that its value is negative, invert its bits, and subtract 1:

```
DateTime myDate = ... // desired date
int index = list.BinarySearch(Tuple.Create(myDate, 0), TupleCompare.Instance);
if (index < 0) {
    var res = ~index-1;
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Exact match at index {0}", index);
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/uZ0cFw)

Comment: This is excellent thank you!  If I wanted to reverse it to be `<=` (not `>=`) how would I do this?  I've tried removing the `-` in the `-x` line but it doesn't seem to give expected results.

Comment: @TomGullen The `-` in the comparator is to compensate for the reverse order of items in your list. If you want the next lower item, use `~index+1`. Compare the result to `list.Count` to make sure it's not past the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a trick to use existing binary search algorithm. for descending order simply use negative values.

```
List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();

list.Add(Convert.ToDateTime("29 Jan"));
list.Add(Convert.ToDateTime("25 Jan"));
list.Add(Convert.ToDateTime("20 Jan"));
list.Add(Convert.ToDateTime("10 Jan"));
list.Add(Convert.ToDateTime("3 Jan"));

var comparer = Comparer<DateTime>.Create((x, y) => -x.CompareTo(y)); // notice negative
var search = Convert.ToDateTime("2 Jan");

var find = list.BinarySearch(search, comparer);
if (find < 0) find = ~find - 1; // minus 1 because ordered by descending

Console.WriteLine(find);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Data;

using System.Xml.Serialization;



namespace ConsoleApplication20
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Tuple<DateTime, int>> list = new List<Tuple<DateTime,int>>() {
                new Tuple<DateTime,int>(new DateTime(2018, 1,29),0),
                new Tuple<DateTime,int>(new DateTime(2018, 1,25),1),
                new Tuple<DateTime,int>(new DateTime(2018, 1,20),2),
                new Tuple<DateTime,int>(new DateTime(2018, 1,10),3),
                new Tuple<DateTime,int>(new DateTime(2018, 1,3),4)
            };


            List<DateTime> searchDates = new List<DateTime>() { new DateTime(2018, 1, 1), new DateTime(2018, 1, 5), new DateTime(2018, 1, 28), new DateTime(2018, 2, 1) };

            foreach(DateTime date in searchDates)
            {
                int results = BinarySearch(list, date);
                Console.WriteLine("Input Date : '{0}', index : '{1}'", date.ToShortDateString(), results);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static int BinarySearch(List<Tuple<DateTime, int>> list, DateTime date)
        {
            var results = list.Select(x => new { diff = (x.Item1 - date).Days, index = x.Item2 }).Where(x => x.diff >= 0).OrderBy(x => x.diff).FirstOrDefault();
            return results == null ? -1 : results.index;
        }




    }


}
```